# Creating SAML 2 SSO token request using WIF

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wif

I have an example SAML compliant XML request:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_[GUID]" IssueInstant="[DATETIME]" Version="2.0" AssertionConsumerServiceIndex="0" >
   <saml:Issuer>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</saml:Issuer>
   <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"/>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

How can I generate this request using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2?
I can't find any references online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

This is part of the SAML protocol.

After successful authentication, a SAML token is returned which is where the class you referenced comes in.

There is no Microsoft SAML protocol stack.

Have a look at [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html) for some ideas.

(WIF is actually WS-Federation which is a different protocol).

Comment: Actually I used OneLogin toolkit for ADFS and it didn't worked right away since ADFS by default expects request to be compressed